# SSRS Formatting Number

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm having troubles using an expression in one on my textboxes. I need all null values to display as 0, which I have done correctly. However, if the number is a decimal, say 126.5000, I need it to just display as 126. I was thinking about using the FIX function like so...

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Sum(Fields!PROP__QTY.Value)), "0", Fix(Sum(Fields!PROP__QTY.Value)))
```

however when I do that I get #ERROR where the 0's should be displayed. The fix function works though. If I take the Fix out, then the 0's display proper as well. Is my syntax not correct? I'm fairly new with SSRS so any guidance would be awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be mixing types try , 0 , rather than , "0" , as this changes it from a number to text

I personally would use CInt to convert the result rather than Fix
=IIF(IsNothing(Sum(Fields!PROP__QTY.Value)), "0", CInt(Sum(Fields!PROP__QTY.Value)))